# Casting from object to IList<T> derived class: foreach fails

Tags: c#, foreach, casting, ienumerable

I have a custom `class MyList<T> : MyBaseList, IList<T>` and some instances of it `myList1, myList2...`, which i store as `object` (comes from reflection, i can not change) in a `List<object> ListOfLists = new List<object>()`, so for example `myList1` boxed as an `object` is stored at `ListOfLists[0]` and so on.

My class `MyList<T>` implements:

```
private List<T> items = new List<T>();
...
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
   return this.items.GetEnumerator();
}
```

When trying to iterate through every element of `myList1, myList2...` like...

```
bool Iterate<T>(T targetElem)
{
   foreach (var listObj in ListOfLists)
   {
      var myIList= (IList<T>)listObj;
      var myEList = myIList.Cast<MyList<T>>();

      foreach (var myList in myEList)
      {
         foreach (var listElem in myList)
         {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(listElem , targetElem)) return true;
         }
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

... I receive Error `System.InvalidCastException` at `foreach (var myList in myEList)`.

Has anyone an idea on how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `MyList<T>`?

Comment: a custom class that accepts any object... updated

Comment: Please post a [mcve], so we can actually reproduce your issue locally.

Comment: What is your `Iterate` method supposed to do? Check if an element is in the list of lists? I feel like you have an extra foreach loop...

Comment: My `ListOfLists` contains many instances of `MyList<T>` boxed as object; `listObj´ is each of these objects (boxed lists) that I retrieve from `ListOfLists`.

Comment: @Sweeper: My `Iterate` method checks if  any list `myList1, myList2...` in my `ListOfLists` contains the given `targetElem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have written an extra `foreach` loop. To iterate over a list of lists, you only need 2. You also seem to be trying to cast each `T` object in each sublist to `MyList<T>`, which doesn't make much sense.

You probably intended this:

```
foreach (var listObj in ListOfLists)
{
    var myIList= (IList<T>)listObj;

    foreach (var listElem in myIList)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(listElem , targetElem)) return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

I don't know why you are so sure that every sublist must be a list of `T`. Maybe one of them isn't, who knows? If this is the case, you can use `as` to cast and check for null:

```
foreach (var listObj in ListOfLists)
{
    var myIList= listObj as IList<T>;

    if (myIList == null) continue;

    foreach (var listElem in myIList)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(listElem , targetElem)) return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
var myEList = myIList.Cast<MyList<T>>();
```

Here you are trying to cast every item in `myIList` to an instance of `MyList<T>`. Since the execution of `Cast` is deferred you get the error not before the `foreach`.

As far as I understand your intention you should do

```
var myEList = myIList.Cast<T>();
```